# expected function body after function declarator codeblocks

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am trying to code a little program which calculates the price with fees.

There is two error messages :

> 7 : "Expected function body after function declarator"
>
> 9 :  Expected identifier or "("

The code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()

    var float : prix_ht,prix_ttc;

{

    //La taxe vaut 2,6 euros

    //Saisie du prix hors taxes
    printf("Saisir le prix hors taxes");
    scanf("%f",&prix_ht);

    prix_ttc==(prix_ht)+(2.6);

    printf("Le prix ttc est :%f",&prix_ttc);

    return 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: don't post images of your code, copy it directly into the question.

Comment: If the purpose of the image is to provide extra information, then it is not serving it. It's unreadable.

Comment: Aside: please see [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)

Comment: `var float : prix_ht,prix_ttc;`  --> This doesn't look like a C language way of the variable declaration.

Comment: @H.S. as already answered.

Answer (score 1):

```
var float : prix_ht,prix_ttc;
```

is not C code, you declare variables like this:

```
float prix_ht, prix_ttc;
```

And you should write this line inside your `main` function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int main()
{
    float prix_ht, prix_ttc;

    //La taxe vaut 2,6 euros

    //Saisie du prix hors taxes
    printf("Saisir le prix hors taxes");
    scanf("%f",&prix_ht);

    prix_ttc==(prix_ht)+(2.6);

    printf("Le prix ttc est :%f", prix_ttc);

    return 0;
}
```

Also note that I fixed your last `printf` line, you were passing a pointer to
`float`.

And you should check the return value of `scanf`, you don't know if it was able
to read a `float` and convert it. You should do

```
if(scanf("%f", &prix_ht) != 1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Could not read float for prix_ht\n");
    return 1;
}
```

And double `==` is for comparing

```
    prix_ttc==(prix_ht)+(2.6);
```

compares the value `prix_ttc` with `prix_ht+2.6`, it is not assigning it. You
should use only one `=`:

```
    prix_ttc=(prix_ht)+(2.6);
```

Comment: @WeatherVane good catch, I missed the `==` instead of `=` on my first look at the code.

Answer (score 0):

just put { after int main() and remove { on line no. 5